# Never Combine grayed out

Tags: windows, taskbar

I want to set the taskbar at the bottom to always combine the buttons in Windows 7. When I go to Taskbar and Start Menu Properties to change it, I see that it is set to "never combine", but the "Always combine, Hide Labels" option is grayed out. How can I access this option?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using exactly?  Update your question with this information.

Answer (score 3):

There is a registry setting that enables or disables this feature. You can used the Registry Editor (Start > Run > regedit) to edit the following keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoTaskGrouping

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoTaskGrouping
```

By setting their value to "0", you will be able to select the grouping options in the taskbar properties.

For more information, or for an alternative way to modify this setting, check out: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/118986-taskbar-button-grouping-allow-prevent.html